# sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am running into this sqlachemy error that I haven't been able to understand:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class '__main__.JobRecord'>'
```

What does this error mean? What are possible causes?

This is the method that triggers the error:

```
@classmethod
def find_job_record_from_pk(cls, pk):
    '''
    return the job record with the given pk
    '''
    job_record = MlcDb.get_session().query(cls).filter(cls.pk == pk).first()
    return job_record
```

Mapping:

```
@classmethod
def define_mapping(cls):
    '''
    SQLAlchemy mapping definition
    '''
    cls.mapper = mapper(cls, cls.table, 
        polymorphic_on = cls.table.c.item_type, 
        properties = {
            'item_type': synonym('_JobRecord__item_type', map_column=True),
            'version': synonym('_JobRecord__version', map_column=True),
            'state': synonym('_JobRecord__state', map_column=True),
            'date_created' : synonym( '_JobRecord__date_created', map_column=True)
        }
    )
```

Comment: Please provide the original code which create problem. Your code is in  segments so we cant generate same error to solve it. If we can create the same error then we can solve it.

Comment: also, show the *full* stack trace, not just the last line.

Comment: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/1476

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error ocurred because I forgot to extend from "Base" in the class Definition.
Base on the given error it's probable that it was declared as
follows:

```
JobRecord:
     pro1: Column()
```

instead of

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
JobRecord(Base): #here is the missing extend
     pro1: Column()
```

The messages says that "the parameter is not recognized.

According to the documentation

> Classes mapped using the Declarative system are defined in terms of a base class which maintains a catalog of classes and tables relative to that base - this is known as the declarative base class

And it's important to notice that:

> Our application will usually have just one instance of this base in a commonly imported module. We create the base class using the declarative_base() function

Of course all this helps me in my particular case

I hope this is useful.

more info:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html

Answer (score -7):

try `filter_by(pk = pk)` instead